# How to make another Key acting like Enter

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard, mapping, enter

my question is kinda simple but I didn't find any answer.

I have a WPF application and I want to remap the behaviour of Tab and Enter keys onto other keys, because I need them to be close on the keyboard.

I already managed to make a letter key (for example J) acting like Tab Key, but I can't find a way to make a close button (for example K or H) acting like Enter!

For instance, I need this because the application works only with keyboard, so when an element (for example a button) has focus, I would like to press K or H to act like Enter key and do something. All works fine if I press the real Enter key but as I said, I would like to remap this function to another Key.

Is this possible? If so, how to do it in a WPF application?

Comment: You can use SendKey.Send method. Catch key down and check if it K or H then send key as enter http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'm not sure but I'd prefer something that works worldwide on the application, I don't want to set that line of code in every single button or control in my application (if possibile)